# Search Text Web Parts Content using PNP Modern Search

Tags: search, pnp, modern

Using PNP Modern Search, how can I search for Text Web Parts content on site pages?

Answer (score 0):

Text content added to pages via text web parts are indexed by Microsoft Search. Using the PnP search web parts should return any pages containing that content.

Comment: Unfortunately, no pages are returned.  Is there a setting that I might be missing?  For query template, I'm using {searchTerms}